# app.render [TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined] Using Express with Gaikan in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

res.render is working perfectly:

```
res.render('main', function(err, html){
    // Returns '<html></html>' contained inside of 'views/main.html'
    console.log(html);
});
```

But my app.render:

```
app.render('main', function(err, html){
    // Returns undefined
    console.log(html);
});
```

The error being returned by app.render is:

```
[TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined]
```

I assume it's trying to set data.content (being part of Gaikan), but I don't know for certain, and I don't know what the problem is.

Help would be appreciated.

Stack trace: http://puu.sh/5qGSq.png

Config:

```
var express = require('express'),
    gaikan = require('gaikan');

app.configure(function() {
    app.engine('html', gaikan);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

    gaikan.options.scoped = true;
});
```

As stated above, the template is just `<html></html>`.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `gaikan@1.3.13` and `express@3.4.4`. Try re-throwing the error to see if the stacktrace yields more information (`if (err) throw err;`). Also, try with an empty object as second argument: `app.render('main', {}, function(err, html) { ... });`

Comment: Righto, thanks for the attention. I'll give it a go now and let you know.

Comment: I'm running gaikan@1.3.13 and express@3.4.3, -edit- The stack trace doesn't yield anything I find useful, I'll screencap it shortly.

Comment: http://puu.sh/5qGSq.png

Comment: Can you show us your template and the way you set up Gaikan for express?

Comment: Updated question with the information you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue of Gaikan making an assumption that isn't true, namely that the `options` argument – which is passed to the render function – always contains a `_locals` property.

Looking at the Express code, that property is only guaranteed to exist when calling `res.render()`, but when you call `app.render()` you need to explicitly pass it yourself before Gaikan works:

```
app.render('main', { _locals : {} }, function(err, html) { ... });
```

The reason why I couldn't reproduce it is because this issue only occurs when `gaikan.options.scoped === true`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :D Fixed it completely.